# Node-webkit + Angular.js Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: angularjs, node-webkit

I've got this files

```
lib/
 |-angular.min.js
 |-angular-route.js
 |-angular-resource.js
index.html
package.json
```

The main `index.html`

```
<html ng-app="example">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <script src="lib/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-resource.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('example', ['ngRoute']);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the `package.json`

```
{
    "main": "index.html"
    , "name": "example"
    , "version": "1.0.0"
    , "window": {
        "toolbar": true
        , "frame"  : true
    }
}
```

But when I run the `$ nw .` it throws me this error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.7/$injector/moduler...
```

Comment: there maybe a path problem with the resources ,you can use CDN instead of local directory .

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problem with ng Animate. It has turned out that I had installed newer version of ngAnimate than angular.js which I use. So to be sure, just check versions angular and other components.

- angular.js - v1.2.7
- angular-route - v1.2.7
- angular-resource - v1.2.7